# Patterns for resetting objects to initial state

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, member-initialization

Suppose I have an object with a member that is expensive to construct, and the need for a `reset()` function that resets it to its initial state:

```
struct Example
{
    // option 1: efficient, but need to duplicate initialization logic of reset() 
    Example(int param) : expensive_member_(param), param_(param)
    {
    }
    /* option 2: less code, but initializes expensive_member_ twice
    Example(int param) : param_(param)
    { 
        reset();
    }*/

    void reset()
    {
         expensive_member_ = ClassWithExpensiveConstructor(param_);
    }

    ClassWithExpensiveConstructor expensive_member_;
    int param_;
}
```

Is there a better way of/pattern for efficiently resetting the object to its initial state without duplicating the initialization logic in the initializer list and the `reset` function?

**edit:** If there is no generic way of achieving what I want, that is also an acceptable outcome of this question!

Comment: You could give `ClassWithExpensiveConstructor` a reset method of its own that does the most efficient reset possible.

Comment: why not make expensive_member_ a pointer?

Comment: @JonathanPotter wouldn't that just move the problem somewhere else? I.e. I would have to worry about the duplicate code in `ClassWithExpensiveConstructor` instead of `Example`?

Comment: Really depends on your case.  Maybe have a pool of ClassWithExpensiveConstructor objects and reuse them, assuming it's possible?  I don't think there is a good generic solution.

Comment: To extend on Jonathan's comment: Resetting a class might be cheaper, than newly creating one. E.g. some containers could reuse the existing capacity.

Comment: Even then, however, the pointer solution gives you a cheap move constructor and assignment operator if you need them, so it might be advantageous to combine both approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `ExpensiveMember` a pointer, in such case your option 2 will not call `ExpensiveMember` constructor in `Example` constructor unless you explicitly call it:

```
struct Example
{
    Example(int param) : expensive_member_(), param_(param)
    { 
         reset();
    }

    ~Example() {
         delete expensive_member_;   // better use unique_ptr etc
    }

    // Also a copy constructor and assignment operator 
    // are needed to avoid memory problems such as double-delete.
    // Also, better use unique_ptr etc.
    // This answer does not use unique_ptr just to make the main idea more clear.

    void reset()
    {
         delete expensive_member_;   // better use unique_ptr etc
         expensive_member_ = new ClassWithExpensiveConstructor(param_);
    }

    ClassWithExpensiveConstructor* expensive_member_;  // better use unique_ptr etc
    int param_;
}
```

Comment: @anderas, fixed. Did not want to use `unique_ptr` in answer so that the main idea (the pointer does not require initialization) is not hidden.

Comment: Better :-) Though, it's not necessary to check for `nullptr` befor deleting the pointer. Would you mind if I accepted @kiviak's solution? Your posts have the same basic idea, but he was quicker so I think that would be fair.

Comment: @anderas, you may accept what you like more, but actually my answer is earlier... :)

Comment: oops, sorry, my bad! Hard to decide which answer is better. Both look equally good to me...

Comment: @anderas: having accepted this answer shows me I misundertood your question, since I assumed that `expensive_member_` needed to be initialized in the constructor. In this case, I find it a design flaw that you may have an object with an uninitialized member: it ignores RAII. If you prefer not to construct the `expensive_member_` at `Example`'s construction time, then I would implement a lazy initialization mechanism within `Example` instead of forcing the client code to call `reset()`.

Comment: @AntonioPérez, note that in this answer, `reset()` is called by the constructor.

Comment: @Petr: then what is the benefit over the OP's code?

Comment: @AntonioPérez, over version 1 --- no code duplication (in constructor list and in `reset()`); over version 2 --- no implicit call to expensive constructor in `Example` constructor.

Comment: @AntonioPérez:  right, the last comment of Petr is spot-on.

Comment: Ok for version 1, if code looks like that in kiviak's answer. But for option 2, both kiviak's and your answer implicitly call expensive constructor in `Example`'s. Besides, you are using dynamic memory allocation when not strictly needed.

Comment: @AntonioPérez, I don't quite get it --- my answer has one version only.

Comment: @Petr: I meant that I don't get your claimed improvement over option 2 in your previous comment.

Comment: @AntonioPérez, in OP's option 2, the `expensive_member_` will first be initialized with a default constructor (because it is not mentioned in member initializer list), and then overwritten in a call to `reset()`. In my solution, the default constructor is not called.

Answer (score 1):

If `ClassWithExpensiveConstructor` is the one class whose construction/reset is expensive, it should be it which optimizes the operation.

Another option would be to keep a copy of the initial value in a `const` member, assuming that copy construction/assignment is not expensive. That would use more memory, but improve performance if you happen to call `Example::reset()` a lot.

```
struct Example
{
    Example(int param)
    : expensive_member_backup_(param)
    , expensive_member_(expensive_mamber_backup)
    , param_(param)
    {
    }

    void reset()
    {
         expensive_member_ = expensive_member_backup_;
    }

    const ClassWithExpensiveConstructor expensive_member_backup_;
    ClassWithExpensiveConstructor expensive_member_;
    int param_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use a (smart or regular) pointer, so that the cost of initializing the member (i.e. the pointer) becomes smaller, and the actual object is only initialized in the call to `reset()`:

```
 struct Example
 {
    Example(int param) : param_(param)
    { 
        reset();
    }

    void reset()
    {
         p.reset(new ClassWithExpensiveConstructor(param_));
    }

    unique_ptr<ClassWithExpensiveConstructor> p;
    int param_;
}
```

Comment: This does seem like the best idea, though a small explanation would be nice, and `unique_ptr` seems a bit better suited for this job (less overhead and the shared ownership isn't needed here). Would you mind if I (or you) edited the answer accordingly?

Comment: @anderas,i dont mind.i am not good at smart pointer,but i think you can use it as a proxy pattern